# access cookies from Jquery always return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access Application cookies with jquery on my Asp.Net MVC App.

[Screenshot of Cookie and Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndeYf.png)
I am trying to access Cookie with `$.cookie('ASP.NET_SessionId');` but it always returns "undefined"

How can I access Cookie values

[image]

Comment: perhaps it is a `httponly` cookie? can you confirm if it is or isn't, your image chopped off that information

Comment: Have you tried $.cookie('ASP.NET_SessionId').val; , value, text, ...?

Comment: @Dimitri i used only $.cookie('ASP.NET_SessionId');

Comment: That tick under the second `...` column ... bet `...` is `HttpOnly`

Comment: @Jaromanda  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC1cj.png this image may give you clear picture

Comment: yes, clear as MUD ... `...` is the heading ... it should say `HTTP` ... so, it being ticked, you **can't access it through javascript**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP only cookies can not be accessed in JavaScript

And this is a HTTP only cookie